# Ant regexp. Read value of matched expression

Tags: regex, ant

I need to replace all occurrence of some regular expression in xml file with proper values loaded from property file. As example

- in xml file I have `< port=${jnpPort}/>`
- in property file I have `port=3333`

I want to have xml file with entries like `< port=3333/>`

Now using

```
<replaceregexp match="\$\{(.*)\}" replace="${\1}" flags="g" byline="true">
        <fileset dir="." includes="file.xml"/>
</replaceregexp>
```

I get pretty much the same `<port=${jnpPort} />`. I would like value of ${jnpPort} were read from property file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<replaceregexp match="@< port=\${jnpPort}/>@" replace="@< port=$(port)/>@" flags="g" byline="true">
        <fileset dir="." includes="file.xml"/>
</replaceregexp>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just use copy with a filterset

`<filterset id="version.properties.filterset" begintoken="$" endtoken="$">`
`<filter token="jnpPort" value="${port}" />`
`</filterset>`

`<copy file="file.xml.template" tofile="file.xml" overwrite="true" >`
`<filterset refid="version.properties.filterset" />`
`</copy>`

Okay, not quite copy in place, but pretty good.

Comment: Ok thanks. It will work and I have tried this, but I am looking for something more generic. I do not want to define values which should be replaced but it should be based on regular expression. For example in one file there will be different number of < port=${something} /> combination. And I would like that ${something} will determine which value will be set from property file.